# RSpec for characters count

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to create rspec file for counting characters. I use this code:

```
private

def generate_transaction_id(length = 25)
   chars = [*('a'..'z'), *(0..9)]
   (0..length).map {chars.sample}.join
 end
```

**rspec:**

```
it "checks transaction id length" do
      trx_id = request.send("generate_transaction_id")
      puts trx_id
      expect(trx_id).to have(25).characters
    end
```

Output:

```
.lt3s5gxr0zkm02d0gf2f0vce1o
Fsome output
.

Failures:

  1)  with no argument checks transaction id length
     Failure/Error: expect(trx_id).to have(25).characters

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `have' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Anonymous::WithNoArgument:0x007fde1f0fb590>
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure why do you think `rspec` understands a human language.

```
expect(trx_id.length).to eq(25)
```

Comment: That kind of dsl IS (was?) available in some places, though. I have personally used it on arrays/collections: `expect(ary).to have(3).elements` or `expect(project).to have(5).documents`. If it's not available now, then they must have cut it out at some point. Or maybe it's only a matter of including an add-on DSL module? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯